# access the certificate used on an SSL connection

Tags: javascript, security, ssl

How can Javascript code running in a page inspect the certificate chain used to authenticate the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't. SSL context information is not exposed to Javascript.

Moreover, even if it did, it'd be worthless. If there were someone tampering with the connection, they could simply replace the Javascript code which examined the SSL context with a substitute which treated it as safe.

Comment: My thought was to use aggressive cache control to ensure that the checking code doesn't get updated once deployed.

Comment: Wouldn't work. An attacker could simply manipulate the parent page to point to a different script file, for instance. Once you've lost trust in the integrity of your own code, there's no way to regain it.

Comment: it would be the parent page that contained the code.  But yes, if you don't trust governments to not sign intercept certs, the web just isn't secure.

Comment: I disagree that it's worthless - the ability to turn a highly reliable attack into an unreliable attack is useful.